# Java declare a class object from the string of that class?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a script provided from the client like this

```
segment-id Integer
segment-description String
```

Now I want to build a class with the following methods

```
Sample sample = new Sample();

// casting to the type specified in the script
(map.get("segment-id")) segmentId = sample.get("segment-id");

// Now it can be used as an Integer
Integer result = segmentId + 2;
```

---

Is it possible to do something like

```
Class<map.get("segment-id")> segmentId = new Class<map.get("segment-id")>();
```

Or any better solution...? I need a way create objects of specific type, which I don't know in advance.

My current solution is

```
public Integer getInteger(String key) {
    return map.get(key);
}
```

but in this way I have to know in advanced `segment-id` is of type `Integer`.

Comment: what do you mean "the String of that class" ?

Comment: He means instantiate a class given a string representation of its name.  This can be done using reflection, but you will need the fully qualified class name.

Comment: @Stultuske: the string name of that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Class.forName()` to get the class and `.newInstance()` to get a new instance:

```
Object createdObject = Class.forName("java.lang.String").newInstance();
```

or ...

```
Object createdObject = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer").newInstance();
```

If you need to know if it's a String:

```
if(createdObject instanceof String) {
    String castValue = (String) createdObject;
    ...
}

if(createdObject instanceof Integer) {
    Integer castValue = (Integer) createdObject;
    ...
}
```

But you could just test the incoming string:

```
if("java.lang.String".equals(nameOfClassToCreate)) {
    ....
}
```